# How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?

Tags: javascript, split

I have this string

```
'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345'
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into

```
var name = "john smith";
var street= "123 Street";
//etc...
```

Answer (score 994, accepted):

With JavaScript’s [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
var input = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';

var fields = input.split('~');

var name = fields[0];
var street = fields[1];
// etc.
```

Answer (score 96):

According to ECMAScript6 `ES6`, the clean way is destructuring arrays:

```js
const input = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';

const [name, street, unit, city, state, zip] = input.split('~');

console.log(name); // john smith
console.log(street); // 123 Street
console.log(unit); // Apt 4
console.log(city); // New York
console.log(state); // NY
console.log(zip); // 12345
```

You may have extra items in the input string. In this case, you can use rest operator to get an array for the rest or just ignore them:

```js
const input = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';

const [name, street, ...others] = input.split('~');

console.log(name); // john smith
console.log(street); // 123 Street
console.log(others); // ["Apt 4", "New York", "NY", "12345"]
```

I supposed a read-only reference for values and used the `const` declaration.

**Enjoy ES6!**

Comment: You can also skip an item: `const [name, , unit, ...others] = ...`

Answer (score 56):

You don't need jQuery.

```js
var s = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';
var fields = s.split(/~/);
var name = fields[0];
var street = fields[1];

console.log(name);
console.log(street);
```

Comment: You don't need to add regex to this simple replace. It will only make it slower if anything. You can change it to quotation marks for a simple string replace.

Answer (score 17):

Even though this is not the simplest way, you could do this:

```
var addressString = "~john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345~",
    keys = "name address1 address2 city state zipcode".split(" "),
    address = {};

// clean up the string with the first replace
// "abuse" the second replace to map the keys to the matches
addressString.replace(/^~|~$/g).replace(/[^~]+/g, function(match){
    address[ keys.unshift() ] = match;
});

// address will contain the mapped result
address = {
    address1: "123 Street"
    address2: "Apt 4"
    city: "New York"
    name: "john smith"
    state: "NY"
    zipcode: "12345"
}
```

---

**Update for ES2015, using destructuring**

```
const [address1, address2, city, name, state, zipcode] = addressString.match(/[^~]+/g);

// The variables defined above now contain the appropriate information:

console.log(address1, address2, city, name, state, zipcode);
// -> john smith 123 Street Apt 4 New York NY 12345
```

Comment: first we have a string seperated by '~' signs and an array of `keys`. The second replace function is using `[^~]+` to match each different part (i.e. '123 Street', 'Apt 4', etc) and calls the function for each part, passing it as the argument. At each run, the function takes the first key from the keys array (also removing it using Array.unshift) and assigns the key and the part to the address object.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to look into JavaScript's [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), as this is not really a task suited for jQuery.

Comment: substr is now deprecated, so better to use substring() [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring]

Answer (score 8):

If **Spliter  is found** then only

it will Split it

else return the **same string**

> ```
> function SplitTheString(ResultStr) {
>     if (ResultStr != null) {
>         var SplitChars = '~';
>         if (ResultStr.indexOf(SplitChars) >= 0) {
>             var DtlStr = ResultStr.split(SplitChars);
>             var name  = DtlStr[0];
>             var street = DtlStr[1];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

`split()` method in JavaScript is used to convert a string to an array.
It takes one optional argument, as a character, on which to split. In your case (~).

If splitOn is skipped, it will simply put string as it is on 0th position of an array.

If splitOn is just a “”, then it will convert array of single characters.

So in your case:

```
var arr = input.split('~');
```

will get the name at `arr[0]` and the street at `arr[1]`.

You can read for a more detailed explanation at
[Split on in JavaScript](https://codetopology.com/scripts/javascript-tutorials/javascript-string-methods/#splitsplitOn)

Answer (score 5):

well, easiest way would be something like:

```
var address = theEncodedString.split(/~/)
var name = address[0], street = address[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split` to split the text.

As an alternative, you can also use `match` as follow

```js
var str = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';
matches = str.match(/[^~]+/g);

console.log(matches);
document.write(matches);
```

The regex `[^~]+` will match all the characters except `~` and return the matches in an array. You can then extract the matches from it.

Comment: This worked for me! `str.split();` was not working in Firefox, but this worked both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Sandeep, no, `str.split();` [works in Firefox and all the major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
var divided = str.split("/~/");
var name=divided[0];
var street = divided[1];
```

Is probably going to be easiest

Comment: No, you want either `split("~")` or `split(/~/)` but not `split("/~/")`. The latter would only split `"John/~/Smith"` and not `"John~Smith"`.

Answer (score 2):

Zach had this one right.. using his method you could also make a seemingly "multi-dimensional" array.. I created a quick example at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LcnvJ/2/

```
// array[0][0] will produce brian
// array[0][1] will produce james

// array[1][0] will produce kevin
// array[1][1] will produce haley

var array = [];
    array[0] = "brian,james,doug".split(",");
    array[1] = "kevin,haley,steph".split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

This `string.split("~")[0];` gets things done.

source: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

---

**Another functional approach using curry and function composition.**

So the first thing would be the split function. We want to make this `"john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345"` into this `["john smith", "123 Street", "Apt 4", "New York", "NY", "12345"]`

```
const split = (separator) => (text) => text.split(separator);
const splitByTilde = split('~');
```

So now we can use our specialized `splitByTilde` function. Example:

```
splitByTilde("john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345") // ["john smith", "123 Street", "Apt 4", "New York", "NY", "12345"]
```

To get the first element we can use the `list[0]` operator. Let's build a `first` function:

```
const first = (list) => list[0];
```

The algorithm is: split by the colon and then get the first element of the given list. So we can compose those functions to build our final `getName` function. Building a `compose` function with `reduce`:

```
const compose = (...fns) => (value) => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), value);
```

And now using it to compose `splitByTilde` and `first` functions.

```
const getName = compose(first, splitByTilde);

let string = 'john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345';
getName(string); // "john smith"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Try in Plain Javascript

```
 //basic url=http://localhost:58227/ExternalApproval.html?Status=1

 var ar= [url,statu] = window.location.href.split("=");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the splitting on commas question is duplicated to this question, adding this here.

If you want to split on a character and also handle extra whitespace that might follow that character, which often happens with commas, you can use `replace` then `split`, like this:

```
var items = string.replace(/,\s+/, ",").split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as good as the destructuring answer, but seeing as this question was asked 12 years ago, I decided to give it an answer that also would have worked 12 years ago.

```
function Record(s) {
    var keys = ["name", "address", "address2", "city", "state", "zip"], values = s.split("~"), i
    for (i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        this[keys[i]] = values[i]
    }
}

var record = new Record('john smith~123 Street~Apt 4~New York~NY~12345')

record.name // contains john smith
record.address // contains 123 Street
record.address2 // contains Apt 4
record.city // contains New York
record.state // contains NY
record.zip // contains zip
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code --

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split("/");

}
```