# How to get abc from "abc def"?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

```
"abc def"
"abcd efgh"
```

If I have a large string with a space that separates two substrings of varying length, what's the best way to extract each of the substrings from the larger string?

Because this is a string rather than an array, array syntax `s[0]` will only retrieve the first letter of the string ('a'), rather than the first substring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of the `String` object:

```
"abc def".split(' ')[0] // Returns "abc"
```

Works like this:

```
"string".split('separator') // Returns array
```

Comment: just had to post a second before me, didn't you?

Answer (score 9):

```
var arr = "abc def".split(" ");
document.write(arr[0]);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Both above Answer's are right I am just putting it so that user can do some operation with every token. All you need to add a loop for that.

```
function splitStr(str){
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    for(i=0 ;i < arr.length ; i++){
        //You will get a token here 
        // var token = arr[i];
        // Do some thing with this token
    }
}
```

One can return the array for any other operation in other function as

```
function splitStr(str){
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly is the point of the second function, `splitStr`? Isn't it a bit redundant?

Comment: Yes, it is only a sample code or you can say example of the string split feature which returns a array of tokens.