# Javascript string separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to get everything before/after a comma from a string

```
var test = 'hello,world';
```

Result:

```
   var one = 'hello';
   var two = 'world';
```

What would be a good way to this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.split
```

Extra text because I need to write 15 characters for this submission to be approved.

-- edit

okay, more explicitly:

```
var k = "a,b".split(",");
alert(k[0]);
alert(k[1]);
```

Comment: are you serious about the >15 char rule?!

Comment: Yep. (hilariously I can't even write 'yep' in reply to this).

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = 'hello,world',
    words = test.split(',');


   var one = words[0]; // hello
   var two = words[1]; // world
```