# Capitalise the first letter of each word within a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is it possible to capitalise the first letter of each word in a certain class name using jQuery / javascript? I just want to capitalise the first letter of each word of all the fields marked with the class 'capital'.

I just want it to do it as they type, and I know you can do it with css but this is no good as it is stored in the DB as lowercase still.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple jQuery plugin that could do this for you:

```
$.fn.capitalise = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $this.text(),
            tokens = text.split(" ").filter(function(t) {return t != ""; }),
            res = [],
            i,
            len,
            component;
        for (i = 0, len = tokens.length; i < len; i++) {
            component = tokens[i];
            res.push(component.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            res.push(component.substring(1));
            res.push(" "); // put space back in
        }
        $this.text(res.join(""));
    });
};
```

And then call like:

```
$(".myClass").capitalise();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6VEqf/87/).

Comment: Hi thanks for that, should this work ok in form fields ?, I have the in my head, in <script> tags, after calling j query, and my field class set as myClass but when I type it doesnt change anything, could this conflict with another jquery script, or does it not work for form fields ?.

Comment: For form fields you'd have to change `$this.text()` to `$this.val()`, hopefully that'll then work for you :-) You don't have to use `"myClass"` for the class if you don't want to, this was just for my example.

Comment: I also needed to capitalise UPPER CASE TEXT. This modification worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6VEqf/73/ - Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The solution is something like this:

**Working Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Py7rW/7/**

```
$('.captial').each(function(){
    var arr = $(this).text().split(' ');
    var result = "";
    for (var x=0; x<arr.length; x++)
        result+=arr[x].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+arr[x].substring(1)+' ';
    $(this).text(result.substring(0, result.length-1));
});
```

Comment: This will append a space at the very end when there shouldn't be one. "hello world" becomes "Hello World "

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work :)

`$('.capital').css("text-transform","capitalize");`

Comment: Quoting OP: "I know you can do it with css but this is no good as it is stored in the DB as lowercase still."

Comment: Looks like i missed the part about DB (or it was edited)...in that case CSS will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
$('.capital').each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = s[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s[i].substring(1);
    }
    s = s.join(' ');
    $(this).text(s);
}
```

Comment: This does not capitalize the first letter of EACH word, but the first word only.

Comment: Edited the answer. It'll work now. :) I initially thought each word will be in an element with class 'capital'

Comment: I know it will work. Its practically the same answer I posted :) lol

Comment: The answer i posted (as well as you) is basically the most straight forward way for doing this. There was no way i could have posted a 'different' answer. Anyways, yours is more correct with the trailing space correction.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the css text-transform:capitalize to avoid having to run this on every keypress,
and change the actual value of the fields on change.

```
field.value= field.value.replace(/((^| )[a-z])/g, function(a, b){
    return b.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Step to capitalize the first letter of each word :

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#myText', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this. This will capitalize the text in a textbox whenever the text has changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.capital').change(function() {
        var arr = $(this).val().split(' '); 
        var result = ""; 
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
            result += arr[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
            if (i < arr.length-1) {
                result += ' ';
            }
        } 
        $(this).val(result); 
    })
});
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5dMg7/

Comment: Way to throw my code in a different handler and claim it. :) At least you changed `x` to `i`..

Comment: @Dutchie432 I did not copy your code, I'm sorry that you think so.  While similiar, they are different (You are using `text`, I am using `val` because I think OP is using text inputs since it will go into a database). I gaurd against the space at the end differently. Your solution isn't *that* unique.

Comment: No, but my variable names are. I don't care that you did it, but to say something like "I modified Dutch's code a bit to come up with this alternative" would have been nice. That's all.

Comment: @Dutchie432 except that I used [this stack overflow question posted 2+ years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311476/splitting-strings-in-javascript) as reference for splitting the string, which uses `var arr = yourString.split('&');`. I can't imagine it's hard for people to come up with the name "result" on their own for a variable that is a result.