# Can I use just CSS to change color and font size of first letter of every word

Tags: jquery, css

As in the question title, is it possible to change the color and font size of the first letter of every word. For example, like the following image:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with *only* CSS? I could use jQuery but only if it is not possible with a pure CSS or CSS3 solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730037/capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-within-a-certain-class will help for the jQuery solution. It is not possible with just CSS as there is no `:first-letter-of-each-word` selector

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can produce text in small caps with every word capitalized using this CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

But you won't be able to change the color of the initial letters using CSS alone; you're going to have to use jQuery to add `span` elements to your text then style those elements. Something like this:

```
$('h1').html(function() {
    // Very crude regex I threw together in 2 minutes
    return $(this).text().replace(/\b([a-z])/gi, '<span class="caps">$1</span>')
});
```

With this CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

h1 .caps {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjF2S/)

Here you go -

```
<p class="each-word">First letter of every word is now red!</p>

.first-letter {
    color: red;
  }

window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("each-word")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for you script but as i said a pure css solution is prefered

Answer (score 1):

Use the psedo-element `:first-letter` , like:

```
.word:first-letter
{ 
   font-size:200%;
   color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

As the comments suggest, this needs each word to be in its own element, eg. `<span>`

But this is the closer you'll get to what OP wants in pure CSS.

Comment: This is not going to work unless every word is a block or inline block with class="wrap"

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1>The title of this page goes here</h1>​
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var words = $('h1').text().split(' ');
var html = '';
$.each(words, function() {
    html += '<span style="font-size:200%">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    $('h1').html(html);
});​
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hCvsu/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can make each letter strong (bold) and then you can say h1 `strong{color:whatever you want;}`