# Style first letter of each word in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to style the first letter of a paragraph using `CSS` and wanted to add some animation using greensock, But actually the requirement is to style the each word's first letter not just the first letter paragraph.

Whats the suggestion/ideas on this?

```css
p{
  font-size:150%;
  color:#000000;
}
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello This Is The Title</p>
```

**UPDATE** I tried handling the following way (adding span tag and targeting first element of each span) but it doesn't work:

```
p span:nth-child(1)::first-letter {
   font-size: 200%;
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: there is no first-word slector in css. but you can do it with jquery.. If you want jquery solution then let me kno

Comment: Check this if its working for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531680/can-i-use-just-css-to-change-color-and-font-size-of-first-letter-of-every-word

Comment: @SahilDhir please suggest jQuery/javascript solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use just CSS to change color and font size of first letter of every word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531680/can-i-use-just-css-to-change-color-and-font-size-of-first-letter-of-every-word)

Comment: Having a `span`nested inside a `h1`would affect SEO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use with [`split(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for create the array form string  and [`forEach()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) is iterate the each word. Then [`slice(0,1)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNnJPq2NXTAhWIPI8KHbfwAr8QFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_slice_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNGj4ZJADahkdFk8napkEOQPtZv_Lg&sig2=IiexVhx-aVyF9TxplqYZSA) the cut first letter of the word then append with `span` .And add the css effect with  span

```js
var str = $('p').text().split(" ");
$('p').empty();
str.forEach(function(a) {
  $('p').append('&nbsp;<span>' + a.slice(0, 1) + '</span>' + a.slice(1))
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: #000000;
}

span {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello This Is The Title</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const p = document.getElementById('text')

const styleMe = l => '<span class="styled">' + l + '</span>'

const newS = p.innerText.split(' ').map(w => w.split('').map((l,i) => (i === 0) ? styleMe(l) : l).join('')).join(' ')

p.innerHTML = newS
```

```css
.styled {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Hello This Is The Title</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is no css first-word css selector.** So you can use jquery to achieve this.

> **Solution 1:** To style only 1st word of a paragraph .

```js
$(function() {
    $('p').each(function() {
        var text = this.innerHTML;
        var firstSpaceIndex = text.indexOf(" ");
        if (firstSpaceIndex > 0) {
            var substrBefore = text.substring(0,firstSpaceIndex);
            var substrAfter = text.substring(firstSpaceIndex, text.length)
            var newText = '<span class="firstWord">' + substrBefore + '</span>' + substrAfter;
            this.innerHTML = newText;
        } else {
            this.innerHTML = '<span class="firstWord">' + text + '</span>';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.firstWord{ color:red; font-size:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Styling the first word of pragraph.</p>
```

> **Solution 2 :** Too style each first letter of paragraph line

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('p').text().split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
        html += '<span class="firstLetter">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    $('p').html(html);
});
```

```css
.firstLetter{ color:red; font-size:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Styling each  first letter of the word in  pragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a pseudo-element that doesn't exist. There is :first-letter and :first-line, but no :first-letter-every-word.

The easiest option would be to wrap the first letter of each word in a `<span>`. Another option would be to try a javascript solution.

Comment: It's a comment (not an answer).