# Change some properties of specific words in a text

Tags: javascript, css

There is a Costume field on my site that usually contains 3 or 4 specific words, I want the text color , background color , padding and margin Property of each word to be different if the field contains that word.
Also Remove "-" Character(s) from text.
Example:

```
<p id="jds" class="jdsub">baColRed - baColBlue - baColGreen</p>
```

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved using this.
Split each word of paragraph with "-" and then add them back as spans and set the span styles.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43776199/5043141

Answer (score 1):

You can use `span` tag for achieving different formatting for your words.

Like :

```
<html>
<body>
  <p id="jds" class="jdsub">
      <span style="color:red">baColRed</span>
      <span style="color:blue">baColBlue</span> 
      <span style="color:green">baColGreen</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are generating this content dynamically, then add spans in that code and if this is a static website then you can do something like what I showed above.

Regarding, replacing '-', you can pass the entire `<p>` tag's innerHTML to a JavaScript function and replace '-' with ' ' (space character)