# how to split a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

how to split a string in javascript?

example `str = "this is part 1 one wall this is part 2 "`
now I want to split the str in 2 parts separated by word `wall`

so I want output to be:

```
st1 ="this is part 1 "
st2 ="this is part 2 "
```

Comment: where did `one` go?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var str1 = "When I say wall I want to split";
var chunks = str1.split("wall");

alert(chunks[0]); /* When I say */
alert(chunks[1]); /* I want to split */
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll add a regular expressions answer:

```
var splits = str.split(/wall /);
alert("'"+splits[0]+"'"); //'this is part 1 '
alert("'"+splits[1]+"'"); //'this is part 2 '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts = str.split('wall ');

var st1 = parts[0];
var st2 = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = str.split("wall");
var st1 = s[0];
var st2 = s[1];
```