# use javascript to split this string "text[99][text]"

Tags: javascript

I have some input text field in a form that have name with this format:
**sometext[234][sometext]**

Something like `<input type="text" name="user[2][city]" />`

I need obtain 'user','2' and 'city' with split function.

Thank you

Comment: Check if this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493407/how-to-split-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess a regular expression fits better here.

```
var res = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].getAttribute('name').match(/^(\w+)?\[(\d+)?\]\[(\w+)?\]$/);

console.log(res[1]); // === "user"
console.log(res[2]); // === "2"
console.log(res[3]); // === "city"
```

Comment: I'd rather see an id being added than guessing that there is only one input element. :P

Comment: @Shaz: indeed. I just hope the OP already querys for the element somehow. This is just for demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> "user[2][city]".split(/[\[\]]+/)
```

Returns this array:

```
["user", "2", "city", ""]
```

Comment: problem with this is, if for some reason the first numeric value is empty, it would just split into `['user', 'city', '']`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used regexes? Try this sample ([available in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TBzR/)):

```
var re = /(.+?)\[(\d+)\]\[(.+?)\]/;
var result = re.exec("user[2][city]");
if (result != null)
{
    var firstString = result[1]; // will contain "user"
    var secondString = result[2]; // will contain "2"
    var thirdString = result[3]; // will contain "city"
    alert(firstString + "\n" + secondString + "\n" + thirdString);
}
```