# Javascript to substring hours minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to split a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493407/how-to-split-a-string-in-javascript)

Please help me to substring and separate the below string in three variables using javascript.

```
var str="HH:MM:SS";
```

variable 1 is HH
variable 2 is MM
variable 3 is SS

Thanks

Comment: And google next time! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: [split strings in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+split+string+hours+minutes&submit=search)

Comment: @Topener: A) Part of SO's goal is to be the top hit on Google searches, so "google next time" is not a useful suggestion. B) w3schools is a truly *rubbish* resource, recommend MDC or, of course, the specification (though the language is...obtuse).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is `split` ([specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.14) | [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)):

```
var str = "HH:MM:SS";
var parts = str.split(":");
console.log(parts[0]); // "HH"
console.log(parts[1]); // "MM"
console.log(parts[2]); // "SS"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var splits = str.split(":");
if(splits.length == 3) {
    //is valid
    var hour = splits[0];
    var min = splits[1];
    var sec = splits[2];
}
```