# splitting an array with one element into an array with many elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, split

I want to take this array containing one item (*a STRING with a bunch of comma delimited items*)

`["Bucknell Venture Plan Competition, Mitch Blumenfeld, DreamIt Ventures, Deep Fork Capital, John Ason, Mitchell Blumenfeld, Gianni Martire"]`

I want to turn it into this. An array containing each name as a seperate array item.

`["Bucknell Venture Plan Competition", "Mitch Blumenfeld", "DreamIt Ventures", "Deep Fork Capital", "John Ason", "Mitchell Blumenfeld", "Gianni Martire"]`

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the help. That worked!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493407/how-to-split-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript

Comment: Accept the answer, do not update your post saying it worked.

Comment: sorry about that. when i updated it it sitll said 5 minutes til you can upvote. forgot to come back. marked now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple as:

```
var myArr = ["Bucknell Venture Plan Competition, Mitch Blumenfeld, DreamIt Ventures, Deep Fork Capital, John Ason, Mitchell Blumenfeld, Gianni Martire"];
var myNewArr = myArr[0].split(",");
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share the reason for down-voting, or was it out of spite? Clearly it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work:

```
var items = ["Bucknell Venture Plan Competition, Mitch Blumenfeld, DreamIt Ventures, Deep Fork Capital, John Ason, Mitchell Blumenfeld, Gianni Martire"];
var array = items[0].split(",");
```

Comment: it strange how the same answer but you get less upvotes as mr 10k...almost like hes getting followed by ppl and getting voted regardless

Comment: It's probably the "most voted up" gathers most views. After all, he answered just before I did :P

Comment: Yea that is strange, actually no it's NOT. I answered 2 minutes earlier.

Comment: so.. same answer. both deserve the same upvotes. bot of you did the same amount of work and effor within the same time..

Comment: oh -- and 9 upvotes within 10minutes of aksing a question.. are you having a laugh?

Comment: yea yea... it would not seem so conspicuous if the OP had received the same amount of upvotes for asking such a complicated questions..which you answered within a minute then got 9 up votes and nobody else. lol

Comment: omg stop the auto upvote bots already.. everything you say on this page gets upvoted.. booo

Comment: @ppumpkin, where's your answer? You're not entitled to upvotes for answering a question, sorry.

Comment: @ppumkin You should use your efforts to answer more questions instead of moaning.

Comment: Look mate. I answered a bunch of question on this forum.. and it always turns out mr 10K(not him but others like whou have 50k) will get 25 upvotes for a 3 line answer wihtin 5 minutes. Where i actaully try hard to give an answer and get downvoted because i said 1 wrong word. I pledge to up vote everybody around Mr 10K's because they are greedy and dont upvote fellow question answererers

Comment: Everyone starts out with ZERO rep points, sorry that you're expecting it to be more of a socialist point system.