# How to turn a string into an array under a specific delimiter

Tags: javascript

I have this string in javascript:

```
var st="ab,cd,ef,gh";
```

how can make this string as an array with a length equal to 4 example:

```
st should be like this : [ab cd ef gh]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493407/how-to-split-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split(..)`

```
st.split(",")
```

Outputs:

```
["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you an array of four string elements

```
        var st="ab,cd,ef,gh";
        string[] stArray = st.Split(',');
```

so for example

```
        stArray[1]
```

would return "cd"

Comment: The notation `string[]` is not javascript which is what the question requested.  Also, the javscript string method is `split()` with a lowercase S.  I'm guessing that you are specifying some other language.