# how to split a string with ','

Tags: javascript

I have an array of some parameters like:

```
arr=['abc','xyz','how are you, I am good'];
```

I want a result like:

1. abc
2. xyz
3. how are you, I am good

Using javascript only.

I am explaining again something was wrong in last question.
Here is the scenario.

I have 6 string varables having some special charecters.

I assigned these 6 strings to an array like this:

```
arr=[str1,str2,str3.....);
```

After that I am doing:

```
arr=escape(arr);
```

Because some string variable have special charecters.

After that I am reviving this `arr` into other function like this.

```
var newarr=unescape(arr);
```

Now I want to get all six variables from this new `arr`, how can I do this?

Currently I am using the split function like.

```
split(',');
```

But the problem is in this some variables have, inside so it splits twice 
I don't want that.

Comment: it's not clear: do you also want numeric indexes aside? (1., 2...)? *"using javascript only"* : jQuery can be used or not?

Comment: Looking at the orginal vs the 6 other edits, it is totally different. How is this final string supposed to look like?

Comment: var txt = ''; for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) { txt += i + '. ' + arr[i] + '<br />'; } document.write(txt);

Comment: Do you want to create an `<ol>` with the contents of that array?

Comment: i dont want 1 2 3 maintain idex

Comment: i want only 3 strings so that i can pick arr[0], arr[1] like that

Comment: @user1650946 You already have 3 strings in the array and you may pick them with `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc.

Comment: var list = document.createElement('ol'), li, txt; for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){ li = document.createElement('li'); txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]); li.appendChild(txt); } document.appendChild(list);

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493407/how-to-split-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this:

```
arr.join(" ");
```

Here `" "` is a clue.

You man use `"<br />"` to join array elements with the new line.

Comment: sorry vision i updated my question

Comment: I want split that array not join

Comment: @user1650946 Do you want to make a numerated list of array elements?

Answer (score 1):

Umm you can just get them out of the array without split or join

```
var arr=['abc','xyz','how are you, I am good'];
console.log('1. ' + arr[0]);
console.log('2. ' + arr[1]);
console.log('3. ' + arr[2]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hGxM/

​

Answer (score 0):

Use join function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
arr.join(' ');
```

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use split function

```
string.split(',');
```

Comment: Contrary to the title, OP wants to join, not split.

Comment: it will split third string as well. I dont want split that string

Comment: then use indexof() to check if the string contain a , dont split it

Comment: use a for loop to split the data by array index this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
string.split(',');
```

You will get it

Answer (score 0):

Fabrizio, this worked for me:

```
var arr=['abc','xyz','how are you, I am good'];
var res = arr.join("\n");
console.log(res);
```