# How to split a comma separated string and process in a loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to split a comma separated string and process in a loop using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: Does not look like a duplicate. Here is `comma separated string`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

My two cents, adding trim to remove the initial whitespaces left in sAc's answer.

```
var str = 'Hello, World, etc';
var str_array = str.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
   // Trim the excess whitespace.
   str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
   // Add additional code here, such as:
   alert(str_array[i]);
}
```

### Edit:

After getting several upvotes on this answer, I wanted to revisit this. If you want to split on comma, and perform a trim operation, you can do it in one method call without any explicit loops due to the fact that `split` will also take a regular expression as an argument:

```
'Hello, cruel , world!'.split(/\s*,\s*/);
//-> ["Hello", "cruel", "world!"]
```

This solution, however, will not trim the beginning of the first item and the end of the last item which is typically not an issue.

And so to answer the question in regards to process in a loop, if your target browsers support ES5 array extras such as the `map` or `forEach` methods, then you could just simply do the following:

```
myStringWithCommas.split(/\s*,\s*/).forEach(function(myString) {
    console.log(myString);
});
```

Comment: You could add in a trim to take care of leading/trailing white space `'Hello, cruel , world!'.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)`. Wont work in IE8

Comment: If we have a empty string like `''.split(/\s*,\s*/)`; results str.length === 1 instead of 0, how fix it?

Comment: The Regix given in "Edit" part is amazing

Answer (score 33):

Like this:

```
var str = 'Hello, World, etc';
var myarray = str.split(',');

for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
   console.log(myarray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the argument to "split" be ',' ?

Comment: @Archangel: It is, fixed even before your comment.

Comment: what is this "console.log" what is the use of that?

Comment: @learner: `console.log` is a logging function exposed by at least Firebug and WebKit-based browsers. It's generally less intrusive than popping up alert dialogs. One downside is that you have to remember to either remove the calls in production or define an empty `console.log` function, since it won't be available everywhere.

Answer (score 13):

Try the following snippet:

```
var mystring = 'this,is,an,example';
var splits = mystring.split(",");
alert(splits[0]); // output: this
```

**Edit:**

The following snippet will allow you to split, manipulate each element and get the results in an array:

```js
const string = "this,is,a,string";
const array = string.split(",")
  .map((item, i) => `Item ${i} => ${item}`);
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I think you mean `alert(splits[0]);`

Comment: @Andy E: indeed, it was already fixed before I would read your comment, but well spotted nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Please run below code may it helps you :)

```js
var str = "this,is,an,example";
var strArr = str.split(',');
var data = "";
for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; i++){
  data += "Index : "+i+" value : "+strArr[i]+"<br/>";
}
document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<div id="print">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Try the following snippet:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split("o");
console.log("My Result:",res)
```

and your output like that

```
My Result: H,w are y,u d,ing t,day?
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using async/await in a forEach loop:

```
const files = "name1,name2,name3"

if (files.length) {
          await forEachAsync(files.toString().split(','), async (item) => {
    
        console.log(item)
    });
```