# How do I correctly split an array of strings of is it another issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, raphael

I am trying to access a random element from an array of strings as per other examples [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array). I am using Raphael.js and regions[j] below returns an array of Raphael objects - hence the .data(id). This seems to be ok, but theCountyNames, as outlined in the comment below returns all of the strings as one long string. I am guessing that this is why randCounty returns a single random letter, but when I try appending a comma in the loop (+",") and using split as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245088/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-and-process-in-a-loop-using-javascript), I still get one random single letter. Perhaps I am implementing this incorrectly or maybe it is another issue? Thanks.

```
 function pickRandCounty(){
var theCountyNames = new Array();
for (var j = 0; j < regions.length; j++) {
theCountyNames = regions[j].data('id');
document.write(theCountyNames);//THIS GIVES ME THE COMPLETE LIST OF ITEMS IN THE ARRAY BUT ALL AS ONE STRING
//document.write("<hr>");
 }
//var randCounty = theCountyNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * theCountyNames.length)];
//document.write(randCounty);//THIS JUST RETURNS ONE RANDOM LETTER??
}
```

Comment: You seem to be `var`ing `theCountyNames` twice. You seem to be overwriting the old value of `theCountyNames` in each iteration instead of appending. You are also using `document.write`? :(

Comment: Had just noticed the duplicate declaration and edited. The document.write comes from a tutorial I was following here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqLS4oyJ8cA

Comment: It's much better practice to use _Console_ methods such as `console.log` to debug (or test), usually you can open the console with F12, otherwise see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: OK thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append a new item to an *Array*.

```
function pickRandCounty(){
    var theCountyNames = [],
        j;
    for (j = 0; j < regions.length; ++j) {
        theCountyNames.push(regions[j].data('id'));
    }
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * regions.length);
    return theCountyNames[j];
}
```

However, this is not optimised as you can set the length of the *Array* in advance and you can even completely skip the loop,

```
function pickRandCounty(){
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * regions.length);
    return regions[j].data('id');
}
```

Comment: The optimized part is great. I couldn't think in that direction.

Comment: Sound, working now. Thanks. Will take me a while to work through optimised version to understand why it works that way!!

Comment: @Rudra For these types of problems consider the order of operations and whether you can swap them, i.e. _applying a transformation (to an entire array) then selecting one_ **vs** _selecting one then applying the transformation (to the single one)_

Comment: @Paul S  Great suggestion. I would keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in this part of line.

```
theCountyNames = regions[j].data('id'); //wrong
theCountyNames.push(regions[j].data('id')); //right
```

Second mistake

```
document.write(theCountyNames); //it will keep on appending the string in the DOM
document.write("<br>" + theCountyNames);//right
```

Comment: Thanks Rudra, accepted other answer as was first and added more to the solution, but thanks for taking time to help.