# How to split data to get only specific part - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to split data to get like `2018-07-17` from the following code:

```
getCompanyHolydayLeave() {
  this.props.actions.getCompanyLeaveDetails().then(() => {
    if (!this.props.common.getCompanyLeaveDetailsPending) {
     const poyaArray= this.props.common.companyLeave 
     var result = poyaArray.map((poyaArray) => poyaArray.date )
     var  xData= result.toString().split("T")

     this.setState({ companyLeave:xData });  
     }
  });
}
```

My output `xdata` like this.

```
0: "2018-04-29"

1: "18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-06"
​
2: "18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-28"
​
3: "18:30:00.000Z,2018-06-26"
```

I need like this:

```
0: "2018-04-29"

1: "2018-05-06"
```

How can I do so?

Comment: look for a comma in the string and trim everything before it including comma

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala can u show code

Comment: @Gnanaseelan are you looking for formatting dates ?!

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher no ...i have like this 2018-07-17T09:03:08.819Z" in side the array . i need to split to 2018-07-17 like this

Comment: @Gnanaseelan, So you can convert a string to the Date object using formatter.

Comment: @Gnanaseelan added answer `2018-07-17T09:03:08.819Z` to convert into `2018-07-17`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma separated string and process in a loop using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245088/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-and-process-in-a-loop-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can format `xData` with `map()`:

```js
var xData = ["2018-04-29",
 "18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-06",
"18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-28",
"18:30:00.000Z,2018-06-26"];

xData = xData.map(d => d.split(',')[d.split(',').length-1]);
console.log(xData);
```

Comment: @Gnanaseelan, this cannot convert string from `2018-07-17T09:03:08.819Z` to `2018-07-17`. Are you sure about your question?

Comment: @Mamun i got now like this  (2018-07-17 ) format array ..now i need how to  add one day with this array object dates below my out put of  xData array
​0: "2018-04-29"
1: "2018-05-06"
​
2: "2018-05-28"
​
3: "2018-06-26"
​
4: "2018-07-15"
​
5: "2018-07-16"
​
6: "2018-07-26"
​
7: "2018-09-23"

Comment: @Gnanaseelan, manipulating dates like this in JavaScript is quite difficult. Though you can try `map()` to modify the string date by splitting and modifying at the appropriate index....which is again not a smaller task to achieve..........thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can split very easily on Coma (,). After that you need to apply format on date. Below is the code for that :

```
var x="18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-06";
var t=x.split(',') // it will give you array
new Date(t[1])
```

below you can apply formatter for date

Answer (score 3):

### You can use `Date` for that!

> Change in input date format does not affect output format.

---

```
function convertDate(dateStr){
     var _tmp = new Date(dateStr);
     return _tmp.toISOString().split("T")[0];
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
var dateArray = ["2018-04-29","18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-06","18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-28","18:30:00.000Z,2018-06-26"]

function convertDate(dateStr){
   var _tmp = new Date(dateStr);
   return _tmp.toISOString().split("T")[0];
}

var newDateArray = dateArray.map(x=>convertDate(x));
console.log(newDateArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the value in xData.
Just iterate over each value in xData and do:

`xData[i] = xData.split[i](",")[1];`

And you'll have your changed data in the `xData` variable.

Or if you want it to be a little clearer, you can go:

```
var temp = xData.split[i](",");
xData[i] = temp[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the Date class, you can create a dateformat like this:

```
let date = new Date("18:30:00.000Z,2018-05-06");
let dateString = date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

The constructor of the Date class understands all of your 0-4 examples of input using the Date-class constructor. The output is constructed using the date-part of the ISO standard datetime format.

Comment: this out put only like 2018-07-17?

Comment: I just adjusted the answer to fit your needs exactly, with little code :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can convert it your string `2018-07-17T09:03:08.819Z` to Date.

```js
var fromDate = new Date("2018-07-17T09:03:08.819Z");

var formattedDate = fromDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (fromDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + fromDate.getDate();
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Please make sure while using this about the timezone.