# Turning a javascript array into single variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I hope I am using the correct terms as I am a beginner with JS so please correct me if the terms I am using are incorrect. I am collecting `sku` numbers from my website via a `dataLayer` and turning it into a variable called `DL - Product Detail - SKUs` .When the variable comes across it, it's put into a string. Some products may just come across with a single product `sku` string (`sku1`) while other pages have multiple product `sku` string (`sku1`, `sku2`, `sku3`). What I am trying to do now is this: Create them as single variables, something like this:

- SKUS: sku1
- SKUS: sku2
- SKUS: sku3

I honestly have no idea where to even start. So any suggestions would be appreciated. I have something like this but I don't believe this is the correct direction I need to go.

FYI the `{{...}}` are to call the SKUs string from the `dataLayer` using `Google Tag Manager`.

The `_ltk.Activity.AddProductBrowse(productskus);` is where I need to call the SKUs out individually.

```
(function() { 

    var productskus = "{{DL - Product Details - SKUs}}"; 

    return productskus('|');

    _ltk.Activity.AddProductBrowse(productskus);

    _ltk.Activity.Submit();
});
```

I am not really sure how to give a good minimal example but maybe this will help

This is the object that is pulling through:

```
    object  
{
  id: '24513',
  model: 'Government',
  skus: '965000050,965000070,965000146,965000147,965000185,965000244',
}
```

So I created a variable that calls the `skus` out into a string.

```
var sku = ('965000050,965000070,965000146,965000147,965000185,965000244')
```

from that `sku` variable, I now need each item to be it's own `item` for lack of knowing the correct term.

Comment: We need a real minimal verifiable example. What is the data structure being returned? What are they associated values and keys? Not enough information to do much.

Comment: Okay. Let me see what I can create for a better minimal example.

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully fill in some of the holes.

Comment: I think you might just be looking for [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), but I may not be following your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma separated string and process in a loop using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245088/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-and-process-in-a-loop-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can build an array of SKUs by doing this.

```
var productskus = "{{DL - Product Details - SKUs}}";
var skuArray = productskus.skus.split(',');
```

Once you have that array you can iterate over them and call the `AddProductBrowse` method:

```
skuArray.forEach(function(sku) {
  _ltk.Activity.AddProductBrowse(sku);
});
```

I *think* this might be what you are looking to do.

Comment: Yes I believe this is going down the right path. Thank you for the help. The => is no allowed through GTM but I am working on finding an alternative thanks again.

Comment: @EllenHarris I've removed the `ES6` arrow function, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up in case anyone else ever has an issue like this.

I had to create another GTM variable to split the string of SKUs:

```
  function(){
    var productSKUs = {{DL - Product Details - SKUs}}.split(',');
    return productSKUs
   }
```

The I had to update my Custom HTML tag to call out the split sku variable I created above and put it in a for loop to call out each different sku:

```
function() { 

// Repeat this function for every item purchased -> done.
var productsku = {{JS - Split - Skus}};
  for (var i = 0; i < productsku.length; i++) {
    _ltk.Activity.AddProductBrowse(productsku[i]);
}
```

And once I ran that I was seeing the data I needed in the network tab!

Thanks for all the help.