# Splitting a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/gcYeB/

How do I split the string being displayed in the alert box into 2?

So I get an alert box 1 after the other.

The first alert showing

ABC

and the second showing

123

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Javascript [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function.

```
$('.test').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"));

    var parts = id.split('_');
    alert( parts[ 0 ] );
    alert( parts[ 1 ] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the id using the split method and the "_" as a separator.
Then, repeat over each token ($.each) and alert its value.

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    $.each($(this).attr("id").split("_"), function(key, value) {
        alert(value);
    }) 
 });
```