# splitting a string based on delimiter

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

I have a string in following format

```
part1/part2

/ is the delimiter
```

now I want to get split the string and get part 1. How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+split+string

Answer (score 14):

```
result = "part1/part2".split('/')
result[0] = "part1"
result[1] = "part2
```

Answer (score 4):

> split the string and get part 1

```
'part1/part2'.split('/')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var tokens = 'part1/part2'.split('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var delimeter = '/';

var string = 'part1/part2';

var splitted = string.split(delimeter);

alert(splitted[0]); //alert the part1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = YourString.split('/');
```

For your example result will be an array with 2 entries: "part1" and "part2"