# javascript split string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to split a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

how can i split a string into a array in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), using a pattern that matches your separator :

```
>>> 'a,b,c'.split(/,/)
["a", "b", "c"]
```