# how to get data from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such string `test1/test2/test3/test4/test5`
How can I get those tests in separate variables or in array or smth using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: `var arrTests = myString.split("/");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Comment: -1 for terminal laziness. Did you not bother searching first?

Comment: -100 to you. Did you not bother read books only and not visit this site at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrayOfBits = string.split(separator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`
[MN Documentation for split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split)

`var data = "test1/test2/test3/test4/test5".split("/");`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` (so no jQuery required) -

```
var arr = "test1/test2/test3/test4/test5".split("/");
console.log(arr);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/hXLE7/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), where you specify the `separator` as "/" in the API, and get the array of values in return.

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string by a delimiter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split