# How do i get the string from after the third "/"

Tags: javascript

Totally new to programming so kindly excuse the silly question.
I have this URL http://www.blahblah.com/some/thing/blah..

Now i need the string that appears after the third"/" ie., just "/some/thing"..
I dont want to go from reverse as the URL is different for each page but the protocol and the host name is the same..
Is there a way i can extract "/some/thing" along using Javascript..
Appreciate any help..
Thanks!!

Comment: use the split method
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple regular expression here.

One way to get stuff *after* the third "/" just *throw it away with everything before it*.

Basic idea:

```
"/a/b/c/d/e/f".replace(/.*?\/.*?\/s.*?\//, "")
// -> "c/d/e/f"
```

Alternative #1, to reduce repeat:

```
"/a/b/c/d/e/f".replace(/(?:.*?\/){3}/, "")
```

Alternative #2, if input can contain newlines:

```
"/a/b/c/d/e/f".replace(/(?:[^\/]*\/){3}/, "")
```

The `*?` qualifier means "don't be greedy" so `.` won't skip over `/`'s. It's not needed in the negative character class case because `[^\/]` will never match `/`.

This could of course be written in a "less generic" form because because the *real* intent is just to git rid of the protocol/domain portions of the URI (the number of `/`'s is only an observed relationship):

```
"http://foo/a/b/c/d/e/f".replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/?/i, "")
// -> "a/b/c/d/e/f"
```

Note that the last `\/` has a `?` after it so it will return "" for "http://foo" and the `i` is so it will match `HTTP://` if that is used for some strange reason (completely optional, of course).

```
"HTTPS://foo".replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/?/i, "")
// -> ""
```

Happy coding!

---

Note: all of the above regular expressions will extract the content *after* the 3rd `/`, as stated in the question. They will need to be slightly modified to *include* the 3rd `/` in the result. Also, it helps to not ask X-Y questions.

Comment: This looks like some hard core coding.. God! i have a long way to go. Will try this out too..Thank you so much!!

Comment: I just understood these regular expressions and found how accurate they can be:) thanks tried yours and worked just fine..

Answer (score 3):

```
var part = string.split('/')[2]
```

Or more complicated:

```
var string = "/a/b/c/d/e/d"
var arr1 = string.split('/')
var arr2 = []
for (i in  arr1)
{
  if (arr1[i].length > 0)
     arr2.push(arr1[i])
}
var part = arr2[2]
```

Comment: This will fail for `/a/b/c/d/e/d`

Comment: Working now on the second snippet

Answer (score 2):

using the string.split method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str = "www.blah.com/blah/blah/thing/blah.php";
var arrayOfString = str.split("/");
alert(arrayOfString[2]); //coming back to do regex/substring for you
```

have fun! :)

By the way... if you are new to web development, www.w3schools.com was extremely good to me :)

so to respond to your edit you need to do something like this :

assuming above already:

```
alert(arrayOfString.slice(3).join("/"));
```

ok fixed it based on actual needs here.. but like i said, check out http://www.w3schools.com it really taught me some good basics.

to fix for the fail case in the comments do this before the split/slice/join:

`if (str.substring(0,1) == "/"){ str = str.substring(1);}`

Comment: This will fail for `/a/b/c/d/e`

Comment: @pst, i think that fixes the fail case, lemme know if you think of any other failz :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'http://www.blahblah.com/some/thing/blah'
var afterThirdSlash = str.split('/').slice(3).join('/')
```

The `split` returns an array which is the string split on every `/` character. The `slice` selects the part of the array from the fourth element (since arrays are zero-based) onwards, since that corresponds to the part after the third slash. The `join` pieces these elements back together by re-inserting the `/`. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the url begins with 'http://www.blahblah.com/', why not use
url.substring(24)?

Comment: I have two UAT servers and 1 production.. Boss wants generic;)