# How can I trim the text in <asp:label within .ascx up to a "-" delimiter symbol?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I only have access to the .ascx file and not codebehind.

I want to be able to display only the left portion of a string returned by a `<asp:label` control.

I've thought about styling the label as `display:none`; and addind a second `<asp:label` and setting the text property from the hidden control with some javascript manipulation but I can't work out how?

Any ideas?

Comment: What sort of data will be contained in the `<asp:Label>` control?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this on the client side with javascript easily.

if a char ie '-' delimits the sections, you can gt the value with javascript and .split it by '-'

check this out for examples [SO JS Split question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using jQuery, try this:

```
$(function(){
 var text = $("LABELID").html();
 var Index = 0;
 var Length = text.indexOf("-") + 1;
 var text = $("LABELID").html().substring(Index, Length);
  $("LABELID").html(text );
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
     var text = $("LABELID").html().split("-")[0];
      $("LABELID").html(text );
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `.text()` be a better choice than `.html()`? Less chance of grabbing a partial html tag.