# Javascript slice string

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

In my rails app i'm concatenating strings and sending it to javascript via ajax technology. But for encreasing speed i think about one method...
So simple i need to slice my string to three variables:
My string look's so:

```
5.21o-o11.0o-o4
```

So how to slice it to

```
5.21

11.0

4
```

?

Comment: 5 correct answers for 1 minute!

Comment: @Ben becouse some people here are "flying to high" and on questions of nubs simple - downwote( This is not good, becouse in google top i didn't find good solution for me... so opened question here...

Comment: I didnt know js... so opened question here

Comment: @undefined beatifull: there is +41, but i get minus one after another

Comment: @PavelBY That's understandable. It's not the best attitude to duplicate the questions.

Comment: @undefined this is discrimination! becouse i didn't know good english, and on query slice jquery string i didn't get any good result in google! just was good to write split

Comment: That question had been asked in 2008, maybe the first one about this issue.

Comment: @VisioN it is not understandable for me, who didn't know js! Also good practice to set - (( i get frozen my acc, thank's a lot!

Comment: @PavelBY it's OK to ask a duplicated question but if you **Google** the **title of your question** you'll find the answer in the **first page** of results...

Comment: @Adriano i google'd slice! not split! and with slice google didnt get good results! That's the main problem!

Comment: @PavelBY I mean even googling "slice" you get the result in the first page (even if not at the very top of the page). Anyway...why to worry? SO's people are clever than Google to understand what you want! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `o-o` is the delimiter, use `split()` to get it into an array:

```
var foo = '5.21o-o11.0o-o4';
var values = foo.split('o-o');
alert(values[0]); // = 5.21 
alert(values[1]); // = 11.0
alert(values[2]); // = 4
```

This is obviously an example. Normally to get the values out you would iterate over the array as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` method:

```
var arr = '5.21o-o11.0o-o4'.split('o-o') // [ "5.21" , "11.0", "4" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `.split()` method as so:

```
var text = "5.21o-o11.0o-o4​​";
var split = text.split("o-o");
alert(split[0] + ', ' + split[1] + ', ' + split[2]);
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHUzQ/)
​

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using `split` return the array with value

```
var str = '5.21o-o11.0o-o4';
var substr = str.split('o-o');

//substr[0] 5.21
//substr[1] 11
//substr[2] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.split('o-o')` to the string

```
alert('5.21o-o11.0o-o4​​​'.split('o-o'));​​
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var data ="5.21o-o11.0o-o4"; 
var spliced = data.split('o-o');
```