# Find values separated by - in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I get two values separated by "-" like:

```
"first value-second value"
```

What's a good way to find both in JS?

Thanks!

Comment: `"first value-second value".split('-');`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Haha yes I did. Yes I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "first value-second value",
    arr = str.split('-');
console.log(arr[0]); //'first value'
console.log(arr[1]); //'second value'
```

Answer (score 3):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
var str = "first value-second value",
var value = str.split("-");
alert(value[0]);// print first value
alert(value[1]);// print second value
```