# How to trim time part of a date+time string in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am receiving json data in my javascript as a list of strings that contain date and time of certain events.

I construct an array and store these in the array.

**However the storage is in the format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I was wondering if there is a way to just extract the date part of this string from the array.**

```
// run a loop to parse thru all elements in the array. //
t = (Service_date_from[count]); // 't' is what contains the date time once extracted from the array with a counter variable called `count`
```

Is there any kind of date formating functionality in javascript?

Comment: You can split the string on the space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript

Comment: Googling `javascript date` provides a wealth of information on this topic.  The first link quickly describes the functions mentioned below.  Did you even try to search?

Comment: @jahroy yes i did, I have been posting on stackoverflow for a bit, I think I understand the inherent concepts of researching an idea. But I also like discussing an idea at the same time I research. This broadens my search criteria. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @isherwood thanks dude. I lived in St cloud, MN for abt 5 yrs. good times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always formatted that way, you can simply use `substr`

```
var idx = t.indexOf(" ");
var timeStr = t.substr(idx + 1);
```

Comment: yeah dude, I was wondering if there was any kind of date time functionality in javascript to trim variables of date time type ?

Comment: So you'd convert from a string to a Date object back to a string again? There's `t.toTimeString()`, or you could just do something like `t.getHours() + ":" + t.getMinutes() + ":" + t.getSeconds()` if you want more specific control