# How to make an array from a string by newline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, newline

I've got this:

var quoted_text = window.getSelection;

For example:

> Accepting the Terms of Service
>
> The Stack Exchange Network (the “Network”) is a set of related
>   Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers, owned
>   and operated by Stack Exchange Inc. (“Stack Exchange”), a Delaware
>   corporation. Please read these terms of service (“Agreement”)
>   carefully before using the Network or any services provided on the
>   Network (collectively, “Services”). By using or accessing the
>   Services, you agree to become bound by all the terms and conditions of
>   this Agreement. If you do not agree to all the terms and conditions of
>   this Agreement, do not use the Services. The Services are accessed by
>   You (“Subscriber” or “You”) under the following terms and conditions:
>   1. Access to the Services
>
> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Stack Exchange
>   may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the
>   Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, solely for Subscriber’s
>   own use, and not for the use or benefit of any third party. Services
>   shall include, but not be limited to, any services Stack Exchange
>   performs for Subscriber, as well as the offering of any Content (as
>   defined below) on the Network. Stack Exchange may change, suspend or
>   discontinue the Services at any time, including the availability of
>   any feature, database, or Content. Stack Exchange may also impose
>   limits on certain features and services or restrict Subscriber’s
>   access to parts or all of the Services without notice or liability.
>   Stack Exchange reserves the right, at its discretion, to modify these
>   Terms of Service at any time by posting revised Terms of Service on
>   the Network and by providing notice via e-mail, where possible, or on
>   the Network. Subscriber shall be responsible for reviewing and
>   becoming familiar with any such modifications. Use of the Services by
>   Subscriber following such modification constitutes Subscriber's
>   acceptance of the terms and conditions of this Agreement as modified.

How can i make in array from that text by newlines?

I need to paste in the begining of each line simbols "> ", how to do that?

Answer (score 79):

Use [split()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/96428/40175)

Fore example

```
str = "abc\ndef";
console.log(str.split("\n"));
```

will print out

```
["abc", "def"]
```

Comment: You may need to split by "\r\n" sometimes depending on the file.

Answer (score 17):

Use JavaScript `.split()` function to create an array with elements split by '\n'
and then manually iterate through that array and add '<' for each item. The following code may help :

```
var str="How\nare\nyou\ndoing\ntoday?";
var n = str.split("\n");
for(var x in n){   
    n[x]= '>'+n[x]; 
    alert(n[x]);
}
```

Comment: `'> '+str.split('\n').join('\n> ')`