# Splitting a string into 3 substrings jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field in which I write the full name of the employee. I want to retrieve the first word as first name, last word as last name and the remaining middle string as middle name. For eg. for

```
ramesh suresh mahesh roshan
```

the first name should be `ramesh`, middle name as `suresh mahesh` and last name as `roshan`.

Is there any way to do this using jquery/javascript? Please help!

Comment: what is the rule to split

Comment: Suppose u store ur database value in a var x(array),u can split with  `var x=x.split(" ");var a=x1[0];
    var b=x[1];var c=x[2];var d=x[3];` so a=ramesh,b=suresh...d=roshan

Comment: from what I can see something like `'ramesh suresh mahesh roshan'.match(/(.*?)\s(.*)\s(.*)/)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you show me jsfiddle for the same. I am really confused.

Comment: his comment returns an array whose first element is the entire match and the remaining elements, ie. [1] [2] [3] are the captured groups, ie. first name, middle name, last name. you can store the result in the variable like so: `var namearray = somestringvariable.match(/(.*?)\s(.*)\s(.*)/)` and access the names like so: `namearray[1]` would retrieve the first name. if you have a user input or html element you can use something like: `$('input').val().match(/(.*?)\s(.*)\s(.*)/)` or `$('div').text().match(/(.*?)\s(.*)\s(.*)/)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny your regex fails with "John Smith" xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach

1. Split the string based on space using **`string.split(" ")`**.

Then usually,

1. `0`th index - represents *first name*
2. `(last - 1)`th index - represents the *last name*
3. So for *middle name* I'm `iterating the remaining index and
   concatenating` each other.

---

```
var name = "ramesh suresh mahesh roshan";
var d = name.split(" ")

console.log("first Name : " + d[0]);
console.log("Last Name : " + d.length != 1 ? d[d.length -1] : "");
var mid = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= d.length - 2; i++) {
    mid = mid + " " +  d[i];
}
console.log("middle name: " +mid);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFPkx/3/)

Comment: This is a bit fragile because it will break if there is only a first and last name, or even just a first name.

Comment: @Peter In my form its compulsory to write the first name and last name. So it works for me.

Comment: @DarkKnight Even so, unless you handle these cases you open up the opportunity for nasty bugs—for example, this allows a case where the user can enter just a first name, and now you have `"ramesh ramesh"` in your system.

Comment: @Peter for your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036322/splitting-a-string-into-3-substrings-jquery-javascript/21036446?noredirect=1#comment31626622_21036621) no, check this http://jsfiddle.net/fFPkx/3/

Answer (score 4):

With this:

```
var fullName = "ramesh suresh mahesh roshan",
    parts = fullName.split(/\s+/),  //Divide by one or more spaces
    firstName = parts.shift(),     //Extract first word
    lastName = parts.pop() || '',         //Extract last word
    middleName = parts.join(' ');   //All the rest
```

**EDIT:** added `|| ''` fallback for lastName in case full name has only 1 word (well, mainly for the paranoic reviewers xD)

Cheers ;)

Comment: *just to let you know* that you need to include a conditional statement to last name otherwise it will fail for "ramesh" http://jsfiddle.net/fFPkx/5/

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help you

```
var temp = 'ramesh suresh mahesh roshan';
var fullname = temp.split(" ");
var firsname='';
var middlename='';
var lastname = '';
firstname=fullname[0];
lastname=fullname[fullname.length-1];
for(var i=1; i < fullname.length-1; i++) {
   middlename =  middlename +" "+ fullname[i];
}
alert(firstname);
alert(middlename);
alert(lastname);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9h74/

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick

```
 <script>
        function getnam(){                
            var val = $("#txtval").val();               
            var dssr = val.split(" ");
            var len = dssr.length;                
            alert("First Name:" + dssr[0]);               
            var mn = "";
            if(len>2){
                for(var i=1;i<len-1;i++){
                    mn= mn + " " + dssr[i];
                }
            }
            alert("Middle Name:" + mn);
            if(len>1){
                alert("Last Name:" + dssr[len-1]);
            }
        }
    </script>


    <input type="text" id="txtval"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="getnam()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JavaScript String split() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
var str = "ramesh suresh mahesh roshan";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

```
ramesh,suresh,mahesh,roshan
```

**Definition:** The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

**Tip:** If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.

**Note:** The split() method does not change the original string.

**Syntax:`string.split(separator,limit)`**

**Parameter Values :**

- *separator* - Optional. Specifies the character, or the regular expression, to use for splitting the string. If omitted, the entire string will be returned (an array with only one item).
- *limit-* Optional. An integer that specifies the number of splits, items after the split limit will not be included in the array.

**Answer to your question:**

As many folks already given so many correct answer still I wanted to give some light from my end.

**JavaScript Based Answer**

```
function fnStringSplitter(fullName,separator){
var mName = ""; //Middle Name
var splittedArr = fullName.split(separator);
for (var i = 1; i <= splittedArr.length - 2; i++) {
    mName = mName + " " +  splittedArr[i];
}
alert("First Name : " + splittedArr[0]);
alert("Middle Name : " + mName);
alert("Last Name : " + splittedArr[splittedArr.length - 1]);
```

}

**Calling to function:** `fnStringSplitter("ramesh suresh mahesh roshan"," ");`

**Output:** 3 alerts with first,middle and last name.