# How to access serialized form data and process it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have serialized data on html page and want to process it.

**My data format  is like :**

```
    "lusername=unm1&lpassword=p1&lpassword=p2""lusername=unm2&lpassword=unm2p1&lpassword=unmp2""wusername=unmw1&wpassword=pw1&wpassword=pw2
w2""wusername=unmw2&wpassword=pw1""snmpsettings=pqr""subnet=1.1.1.1"
```

**I want to process above data to sort out final data string as :**

```
lusername=unm1;lpassword=p1,p2;
lusername = unmw2; lpassword = pw1,pw2;
snmpsettings = pqr
```

How do deserilize my data to get above output?

Comment: It should be more easy with some json datas..

Comment: But when I access html elements data by using serialize(), I am getting string gien in question.

Comment: @Superdrac: "The word `data` is the traditional *plural form* of the now-archaic datum". Please don't say "datas"... even as a joke :)

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie ! I also saw that you edited all my posts :D ! Sorry (i'm french).

Comment: How did you create the string to begin with? If you used serialize() would serializeArray have been better for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a split on a specific character see: [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

You probably will need to do multiple splits to give you the proper array structure and values.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var data = '"lusername=unm1&lpassword=p1&lpassword=p2""lusername=unm2&lpassword=unm2p1&lpassword=unmp2""wusername=unmw1&wpassword=pw1&wpassword=pw2w2""wusername=unmw2&wpassword=pw1""snmpsettings=pqr""subnet=1.1.1.1"',
    objs = data.split(/"{1,2}/);
var newArr = [];
$.each(objs,function( i, item ) {
    if( item !== "" ) {
        var parts = item.split( '&' ),
            x = {};
        $.each( parts, function( index, value ) {
            var key = value.split( '=' )[0],
                val = value.split( '=' )[1];
            x[ key ] = ((!!x[ key ]) ? x[ key ] + ',' : '') + val;
        });
        newArr.push( x );
    }
});
console.log( newArr );
```

And here is a working demo: [**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dKLNs/)