# How do I get the String to the Right and Left of a Character in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string such as:

```
http://www.google.com/#anchor-name
```

and I want to be able to get

```
http://www.google.com/
```

and

```
anchor-name
```

into variables?  How do I do it geniuses of the stackoverflow community?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: @Bojangles - However, splitting an URL into it's parts is something different.

Comment: @adeneo True, and this is somewhat of an XY Problem question, but if all the OP wants to do is split on a `#`, the dupe I linked is correct. If they want to parse the URL further then a parsing library is the best way to go. Either way this question is still a dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var parts = str.split('#');
var left = parts[0], right = parts[1];
```

Comment: This has been answered before and can be found in countless Google search result and many duplicate StackOverflow questions. Please don't waste your effort by answering this question

Answer (score 0):

In your situation

```
var str = "http://www.google.com/#anchor-name";
var parts = str.split('#');
console.log(parts)//["http://www.google.com/","anchor-name"]
```

Comment: This has been answered before and can be found in countless Google search result and many duplicate StackOverflow questions. Please don't waste your effort by answering this question