# Regex to select specified paragraphs InDesign

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign

I am trying to find a regex to use in InDesign that could select every nth paragraph in a text box (nth as in random, not as in sequence).

In the following example for instance, I would like to be able to select the 2nd, the 3rd and the 5th paragraph by inputing 2,3 and 5 somewhere in a regex.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that regex is the right tool for this job?

Comment: I don't know of any other option in InDesign to automate this task.. Just an assumption

Comment: What about splitting the text on `\n\n` and treating each part in the split as a paragraph ?

Comment: Because the objective is to use GREP to avoid styling each specified paragraph individually

Comment: You can't select non-contiguous text in InDesign, so the entire premise is wrong. This needs a script, not a regex.

Comment: Yes ok then should I delete this question? Otherwise you could post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs to be done as a script.  See below for an example to get you started. The script assumes that a textframe containing your paragraphs is selected when you run the script! Note: there is no effort to check/handle errors (e.g. giving a non numeric input for paragraph numbers).  You'll need to add this yourself.  You could modify the input to accept a comma delimited list of paragraph numbers if needed as well.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var frame = app.selection[0];

var para = parseInt(prompt("Paragraph:", ''));    

//replace TestStyle with your desired style name
var style = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item('TestStyle');

frame.parentStory.paragraphs[para - 1].appliedParagraphStyle = style;
```

Comment: I think there's something I'm missing here. I run the script, the prompt appears, but then I can only manage to apply a style to a single paragraph in the text box. Let's say I've entered 1,2 only the first paragraph will have the style applied to it.. Everything seems flawless otherwise

Comment: The above code is only a sample. You need to modify it to suit your needs

Comment: I am not fluent at all in JS.. Any advice?

Comment: Refer to this question on how to split a string in javascript.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character.  Then you'll need to loop through all the values in the array, applying the paragraph style to each value - 1 paragraph.

Comment: Hmm.. Wish I could understand. I'm so sorry. Perhaps you could simply edit your answer (the JS code itself) I would love to mark this as accepted and boost you rep.

Comment: Because then you won't learn anything and will just wind up back here next time you have a question.  Better you have a go and edit your question with your most recent attempts.  Then I can give you more pointers on what you are still missing.

Comment: 4 initial lines + following code = success with paragraph numbers marked as CSVs //// for (var i = 0 ; i < paras.length ; i++)
{
    frame.parentStory.paragraphs[parseInt(paras[i]) - 1].appliedParagraphStyle = style;   
}

Answer (score -1):

```
/([^\n]+\n)/g
```

then use grouping to extract the paragraphs you desire.

Comment: Where am I supposed to enter my paragraph numbers exactly?

Comment: @luimeme you make it a function, and your paragraph number is used in grouping, but in the regex.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping exactly? I am not familiar at all w/ regex

Comment: @luimeme depend on your language, global matching should return a list, in which all elements should match the regex. in perl, it goes `my @matched = m/([^\n]+\n)/g;` then just `$match[$paras[0]]` on and on to extract your target.

Comment: Hmm ok in InDesign you can only enter a single line of code in the GREP dialogue box.. No multiple operations. Any way to achieve what I would like to do at once?

Comment: @luimeme if your software does not allow extra code, it's impossible for regex to achieve you goal.