# How to get a number from a string using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have a string `form-step-45`. How to omit the `form-step-` and retrieve only the number using jQuery? The number varies and can be from 1 to ∞.

Comment: Do you mean using JavaScript? There's no need to use jQuery for that. Is the `form-step-` constant?

Comment: What's a likely and realistic upper bound for that number? If they get too large you're going to run into issues storing it in memory.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: this question sure shows a complete lack of research effort

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`

```
 var num = "your-string-with-number-45".match(/\d+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "form-step-45" ;
str = str.replace("form-step-" , "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var final = 'form-step-45'.split('-');
final = final[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    var k = 'form-step-45';
    var num = k.split('-').pop();
```

```js
    var k = 'form-step-45';
    var num = k.split('-').pop();
    alert( num );
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var str = "form-step-45" ;
str = str.replace("form-step-" , "");
```

Comment: it will of course return the number "45" he didn't sayed he want it as integer