# Javascript create array and check 5th element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know if it is possible to take a string and turn it an array, and also check its 5th letter. Like `"I am walking on the street"`, check if its 5th letter is `"z"`,for example.

Comment: You can do this without converting to an array.  There are multiple ways to do this without making an array.  One of them is `.charAt()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Comment: `var mystring = "I am walking"; alert(mystring[5]);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, its not necessary to create an array, but if you want to you can do

```
var string = "This is my string";
string.split("");
```

And then check the letter with

```
string[4];//5th letter
```

You can also use the charAt() statement, like

```
string.charAt(4);//5th letter
```

Comment: Please, remove the space in string.split(" "); It will not split letters but words. And string[4] will return undefined!

Comment: Why would string[4] be undefined? It is part of an array

Comment: You are spliting the string by spaces. string[0] = "This", string[1] = "is", string[2] = "my", string[3] = "string", string[4] = undefined. Look http://jsfiddle.net/e96tyezn/

Comment: My intention was to write `.split("")`, but I wrote it wrong. I was considering that the output would be `["T","h","i","s"...]`

Comment: @gabzerbinato Yes I know, I was pointing out that your fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use String charAt. But it's zero based so, the first position is zero.

```
"I am walking on the street".charAt(4); // Get 5th letter
```

About the array transformation. You can use split function

```
"I am walking on the street".split(''); // will return ['I',' ','a','m', ...]
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I've made a mistake!

Comment: this yields a " " character...cause it takes into account spaces. OP wants letters only...the 5th letter

Comment: @indubitablee The question is not clear enough to indicate that spaces should be skipped, a space is a character too

Comment: @JuanMendes OP said "and also check its 5th letter"

Comment: @JuanMendes actually the string I would use has no spaces. Does it changes the way .split() will be used?

Comment: No. It doesn't! You can just try

Comment: @indubitablee The OP's last comment proves that spaces are irrelevant :)

Comment: @JuanMendes just because OP changed the scope of the requirements doesnt prove that spaces are irrelevant. The code written and suggested should be solid code and maintainable. With your high reputation, you would agree. This answer only works without spaces.  It doesn't prove to be true with the example it uses "I am walking on the street" as .charAt(4) results in a space character and the 5th letter is "a"

Comment: @indubitablee My point is that the OP said letter, but really meant character. The question was kind of vague and you were making a requirement about something that the OP wasn't requiring.

Comment: @nanndoj That's doubtful as the OP has no spaces in their string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an array, we can just check the index:

```
if(str.charAt(5) == 'z') 
    // It is
else
    // It's not
```

Note that this includes a `0th` letter. If you start counting with `1` then use `(4)` instead. This would also count spaces, if you want to only include counting letters where for example `"H e l l o"` where `o` is the 8th letter then you need to remove the spaces from the string first:

```
var stringWithoutSpace = str.replace(/ /g,'');

if(stringWithoutSpace.charAt(5) == 'z') 
    // It is
else
    // It's not
```

Comment: The letter "z" was just an example