# How to replace space with " "

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this :

```
 ["ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE", "0 77.139305 28.795975", "2 77.308929 28.486877", "4 73.820680 18.464110"]
```

I want to make it like this :

```
   var array= ["ID", "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "0", "77.139305", "28.795975", "2", "77.308929", "28.486877", "4", "73.820680", "18.464110"]
```

How to do that ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Is it a string, or an array? Looks like an array to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you actually have an array, here is how to do it succintly:

```
var rows = ["ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE", "0 77.139305 28.795975", "277.308929 28.486877", "4 73.820680 18.464110"];
[].concat.apply([], rows.map(function(row) { return row.split(' '); }))
// => ["ID", "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "0", "77.139305", "28.795975", "277.308929", "28.486877", "4", "73.820680", "18.464110"]
```

Comment: sorry it changed nothing the output is this : http://prntscr.com/6izuoo and the code is this : http://prntscr.com/6izuvb

Comment: From what I can see in the screenshot, you don't actually have spaces as you say in your title, you have *tabs*. Change `row.split(' ')` into `row.split(/\s+/)` to allow for any kind of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
var string_array =  ["ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE", "0 77.139305 28.795975", "2 77.308929 28.486877", "4 73.820680 18.464110"];

var new_string_array = [];

for(var strings in string_array) {
    var x = string_array[strings].split(" ");
    for(var sub_string in x) {
        new_string_array.push(x[sub_string]);
    }
}

alert(new_string_array);
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n5Lkqej/)

Answer (score 1):

It may be done with `reduce`

```
["ID LONGITUDE LATITUDE", "0 77.139305 28.795975", "2 77.308929 28.486877", "4 73.820680 18.464110"].reduce(function(arr, item) {

  item.split(' ').forEach(function(item) {
    arr.push(item)
  });

  return arr;
}, [])
```