# Input Javascript countdown timer minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple countdown timer using Javascript/jQuery.

Basically, I can enter the amount of minutes in the input field and it will convert it to minutes and seconds and starts the countdown.

so, if i enter **30**, it will start the countdown from **29** in this format: `29:59`

What I need to do is to be able to enter the minutes and seconds in the input field and it should countdown properly but I have no idea how to do this.

for example, I want to enter `26:15` and the countdown should start from that time.

this is my entire code:

HTML:

```
<h1>Enter minutes you want to work </h1><p>0:00</p>
<input id="request" type="text" value="<?php echo $end_time; ?>">

<input id="time" type="text" value="">
<a href="#" class="click">Click here</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('.click').click(function () {
    var rawAmount = $('#request').val();
    var cleanAmount = parseInt(rawAmount);
    var totalAmount = cleanAmount * 60;
     $('#request').val(" ");

    var loop, theFunction = function () {

        totalAmount--;

        if (totalAmount == 0) {

            clearInterval(loop);
        }
        var minutes = parseInt(totalAmount/60);
        var seconds = parseInt(totalAmount%60);

        if(seconds < 10)
            seconds = "0"+seconds;
        $('p').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        $('#time').val(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    };

    var loop  = setInterval(theFunction, 1000);

})
</script>
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/71nab0b4/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code for us to be able to help you!

Comment: @MelanciaUK, Sorry but how in the world this question is related to that question in any shape or form?!

Comment: @LShetty, i will in a minute.

Comment: You have a string. Split it up so you have minutes and seconds. You can go from there. Any more than that would mean we would be coding it for you, which is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: splitting a string has nothing to do with converting the numbers to minutes and seconds!

Comment: @H.HISTORY yes it does.. `parseInt('29:59')` will return `29` - you need to split it on the `:` and parse each half.

Answer (score 0):

You want to break your input string into minutes and seconds, then set your `totalAmount` to that value like so:

```
var rawValue = $('#request').val();
var split = rawValue.split(':');

var minutes = split[0];
var seconds = split[1];

var totalAmount = parseInt(minutes, 10) * 60;

if (seconds) {
    totalAmount += parseInt(seconds, 10);
}
```

however, you will likely want to do some validation.

Comment: You should specify the radix for `parseInt`, so `parseInt(minutes,10)`

Comment: @MattBurland only necessary if not working in `strict` mode.. which should never be the case... but added to make you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use split

```
rawAmount.split(':');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/533tkxtu/