# multiple rectangles in Google Maps from SQL database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rectangles, polygons

I am trying to create multiple rectangles with info windows on a Google Map.   I have followed the pattern used for multiple markers  found at [Generating Google Maps markers From Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931548/generating-google-maps-markers-from-database) 
I first used that example and used one of the lat and one of long to display icons on the map.  That worked.  Then I change the code to rectangles and added bounds.   But no rectangles appear on the map.    I tried to hard code one of the rectangles on the map and one rectangle appeared.

I also made sure that the description to be used in the infowindow did not have any links in.  I found that to be a problem if I was passing a link in the data variable.  But I could get the link to work if I add the variable with a link at the point of the creation of the infowindow content.

```asp
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
           {                    
               "title": '<%# Eval("Quad_Name") %>',
               "north": '<%# Eval("poly_north") %>',
               "east": '<%# Eval("poly_east") %>',
               "south": '<%# Eval("poly_south") %>',
               "west": '<%# Eval("poly_west") %>',
               "description": '<%# Eval("smqcomment")  %>'
           }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
  ];


  window.onload = function () {
      var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.78768535298007, -99.96481875),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      };

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);



      for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var data = markers[i]

          var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2, 
              map: map,
              bounds: {
                  north: data.north,
                  south: data.south,
                  east: data.east,                      
                  west: data.west
              }
          });

          (function (rectangle,data) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "click", function (e) {
                  infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                  infoWindow.open(map,rectangle);
              });
          })(rectangle,data);             
      }
  }
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 960px; height: 532px"></div>
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Answer (score 1):

I get a javasript error on your live page: `js:31 InvalidValueError: setBounds: not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: in property south: not a number`.  You need to translate the strings in your JSON into numbers before using them to construct `google.maps.Rectangle` objects.

To open an infowindow on a rectangle, you need to set the position of the infowindow. The syntax `infoWindow.open(map, rectangle)` doesn't apply to rectangles, that only applies to markers (at least for API objects), see [the documentation for more information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add).

> - **position** contains the LatLng at which this info window is anchored. **Note: An InfoWindow may be attached either to a Marker object (in which case its position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself at a specified LatLng**. Opening an info window on a marker will automatically update the position.

```
(function(rectangle, data) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "click", function(e) {
    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
    infoWindow.setPosition(rectangle.getBounds().getCenter());
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
})(rectangle, data);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.492537, -99.901813),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
        north: parseFloat(data.north),
        south: parseFloat(data.south),
        east: parseFloat(data.east),
        west: parseFloat(data.west)
      }
    });

    (function(rectangle, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.setPosition(rectangle.getBounds().getCenter());
        infoWindow.open(map);
      });
    })(rectangle, data);
  }
}
var markers = [

  {
    "title": 'Andrews',
    "north": '42.75001',
    "east": '-103.625',
    "south": '42.62501',
    "west": '-103.75',
    "description": 'Andrews description',
  }

  ,

  {
    "title": 'Arlington',
    "north": '41.50001',
    "east": '-96.25001',
    "south": '41.37501',
    "west": '-96.37501',
    "description": '<img src="http://snr.unl.edu/csd-esic/download/geologysoils/digitalgeologicmapscleaned/Arlington/Arlington_Quad.jpg" height="400">',
  }

  ,

  {
    "title": 'Ashland East',
    "north": '41.12501',
    "east": '-96.25001',
    "south": '41.00001',
    "west": '-96.37501',
    "description": '<img src="http://snr.unl.edu/csd-esic/download/geologysoils/digitalgeologicmapscleaned/Ashland_East/Ashland_East_Quad.jpg" height="400"">',
  }

  ,

  {
    "title": 'Beaver Wall',
    "north": '43.00001',
    "east": '-102.625',
    "south": '42.87501',
    "west": '-102.75',
    "description": 'Beaver Wall description',
  }

];
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

Comment: The problem to start with seems to be that no rectangles are showing up at all.     I first tired removing the section where I define the makers from the REPEATER section and tried inserting your hard definitions of the makers.  And that worked fine. The rectangles showed up.    I went back to my example I started with where I was using the exact same data and where I call the data from the database.   For my lat and long  I used North and East.   This worked fine and the icons showed up and infowindow had the correct information.   I then switched the lat long to South and West --> worked

Comment: Above I meant I went to my example where I was using the same data to display markers instead of rectangles.

So it seems that something how I am defining the markers for the rectangles is where my problem is.   Here is my live example with the rectangles http://snr.unl.edu/data/geologysoils/STATEMAP/PolygonTest.aspx and here is one of the icon tests http://snr.unl.edu/data/geologysoils/STATEMAP/IconTest.aspx

Comment: Do rectangles show up for you in the code snippet in my answer?  If so, please update your question to clarify your issue and provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your data (either real or test) that isn't working.

Comment: I inserted you example of code, including your hard data entry, everything works as it should-rectangles show on the map and when clicked the infowindows appear with the description.   When I subsititute your hard data with the code below
     var markers = [
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
     and so on -- described in the original example,   the rectangles do not display and thus I cannot test the info windows.

It seems I only have about 500 characters I can put in this comment field, how can I put the entire minimal code in this as you asked for?

Comment: I just tested the method that I use to get the data  for rectangle test page exactly on the icon test page.   For the Lat/Long  I used the north/east  and then south/west cases.  IN both examples the icon showed as expected so I think the method I am using to get the data is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I see that geocodezip  updated the code in their original answer to the question.    Two things are new

First the defining of the bounds  applied the function of parseFloat() to each of the coordinates.   I am not sure that was necessary since I have been able to get icons or polygons to draw with the coordinates without this function.

I think what really solved the problem was adding the line of code

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

I am not actually sure what this is doing beside defining the variable "bounds" but it seems to have solved my problem.

Thanks geocodezip!