# Split string by space javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I want to split a string in Java script using 
`str.split([separator[, limit]])`

I want to split it by a space, but `' '` did not work.
What should I use?

Comment: Can you please show the real code you have? Though most likely you're expecting `split` doing its job inplace, but it doesn't, it returns a new array instead of manipulating the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has previously been asked here: [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

In your specific case, based on what you provided, it appears you are attempting to split on nothing. `''` instead of an actual space `' '`.

Comment: Actually there is `' '` in the question. In my edit I've added the back ticks only.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the spaces by commas:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?"; 
var res = str.split(" ");
//Output: How,are,you,doing,today?
```

Like described here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Another option is to use str.replace:

```
Var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var res = str.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
//Output: Mr red has a red house and a red car
```

Like described here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

But what you may actually wanted:

```
var str = "Test[separator[, limit]]Test"; 
var res = str.split("[separator[, limit]]").join(" ");
//Output: Test Test
```

Comment: there is no replace.

Comment: Your tries are either wrong or not connected to the question

Comment: @NinaScholz What do you mean?

Comment: the post, i refer to has changed.