# Javascript sliptstring into 2 variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I could not find any usefull post here about my little question.

I have a variable that contains a string and I want it splited into 2 variables.

Example:

```
var str = "String1;String2";
```

I want:

```
var str = "String1;String2";
var string1 = "String1";
var string2 = "String2";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 3):

```
var string1 = str.split(";")[0];
var string2 = str.split(";")[1];
```

More about split method: [Split String Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: you should accept and possibly vote up if it helped you

Comment: Note that splitting twice is not necessary, using a variable to hold the result of split could be a step towards a DRY solution

Comment: @axelduch yeah, that and make sure there are at least 2 strings to pick

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window object for assigning global variables.

```js
var str = "String1;String2";

str.split(';').forEach(function (a) {
    window[a] = a;
});

document.write(String1 + ' ' + String2);
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? OP didn't ask anything about global variables or the window object

Comment: @sg.cc Nina answered the constraint of having named variables available in the scope. But I suppose one could argue that it is an option not to name them at all in the first place. A compromise could be to underline the fact that it may have undesirable side effects.