# Split string by word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple strings assigned to variables which has a common word. How can I split these strings in to two parts from the common word?

```
var str= "12344A56789";
```

Instead of having to write substring multiple times, is there a way to split the string from `4A` and get the following results?

```
var first = "1234";
var second = "56789";
```

NOTE: Each string lengths are different.

Comment: `str.split('4A')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using :

```js
var str= "12344A56789";
var splitted = str.split('4A'); //this will output ["1234", "56789"]
var first = splitted[0]; //"1234"
var second = splitted[1]; //"56789"
console.log('First is: ' + first + ', and second is: ' + second);
```

see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: How to include '4A' with splitted[1]?