# How do I find all substrings within two common characters in a given String?

Tags: java, regex, string

What I have:

```
String result = "<>hello<!><>Soumik<!><>Having a wonderful day?<!>";
```

What I need:

```
resultStrings = ["hello", "Soumik", "Having a wonderful day?"];
```

Comment: I could work with that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck? How does [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) fail?

Comment: Wait, is it java or javascript?..

Comment: Then why tagged with JAVASCRIPT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

```
result = result.replace("<", "");
result = result.replace(">","";
resultStrings = result.split("!");
```

It's really simple.

I don't know other conditions so it may not be useful. Please add conditions so I can respond to it.

Comment: Too<br>much<br>br! :P

Comment: yep......using the split function helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick:

```
<[^>]*>([^<]+)<
```

Find all matches, and extract capturing group 1 from each.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY9cQ4/1)