# Splitting date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var date = "1st December,2016"
```

How can I split this string to get date,month and year?
I am doing `date.split(" ",1)` then I am getting output as "1st". Now how to get December and 2016?

Comment: [The documentation for split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will provide the answer you're after.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Split by space OR comma (`date.split(/[ ,]/)`).

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could make sure that your string always has that format, the simplest way is to use 2 `split` command:

```js
var date = "1st December,2016";

var arr1 = date.split(' ');
var arr2 = arr1[1].split(',');

console.log('date: ', arr1[0]);
console.log('month: ', arr2[0]);
console.log('year: ', arr2[1]);
```

Update: I just realize `split` could be used with Regex, so you could use this code too:

```js
var date = '1st December,2016';
var arr = date.split(/ |,/);

console.log('date: ', arr[0]);
console.log('month: ', arr[1]);
console.log('year: ', arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **Regular Expression** for that,

```js
 function ShowDateParts()
{   

 var regex =/\s|,/g;
fullDate = "1st December,2016";
var dateParts =fullDate.split(/[\s|,]/g);
alert("date : "+ dateParts[0] + " Month : " +dateParts[01] + " Year : " + dateParts[02]);
    
}
```

Comment: Why is that array index `01` and not `1`?

Comment: `[01]` will fail in strict mode, since it will be interpreted as an illegal octal literal.

Comment: You don't need the alternation in character set `/[\s|,]/`, just `/[\s,]/`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a date object out of my string value and use is to get all values.

Example Snippet:

```js
var date = "1st December,2016";
//reftor to valid date
var validDate = date.replace(/(st)/, '');
//create date object
var dateObj = new Date(validDate);
//get any value you need
console.log(dateObj.getDate());
console.log(dateObj.getMonth());
```

Update:

Snippet to get intended output: (get month as string)

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var date = "1st December,2016";
//reftor to valid date
var validDate = date.replace(/(st)/, '');
//create date object
var dateObj = new Date(validDate);
//get any value you need
console.log(dateObj.getDate());
console.log(monthNames[dateObj.getMonth()]);
console.log(dateObj.getFullYear());
```

Comment: `getMonth` returns a zero-indexed int rather than the full text representation that they're after, so you would have to extend your code to do a lookup for that as well.

Comment: sure will extend snippet now.

Comment: You really should just parse the string to standard Date arguments and pass those, i.e. convert the month to a number then use `new Date(year, month-1, date)`. Parsing a string to create another string that is then parsed by the Date constructor is not recommended. But a Date is not required at all, the OP just wants the parts of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`date.split(" ",1)`

Just use

`var dateparts = date.split(" ");`

And then access each part as an array element.

`var day=dateparts [0];`
`var month=dateparts [1].slice(0, -1);`
`var year=dateparts [2];`

Comment: But this will not split on the comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "1st December,2016";

var dataArray = date.split(/[ ,]/);

console.log('Day:' + dataArray[0]);
console.log('Month:' + dataArray[1]);
console.log('Year:' + dataArray[2]);
```