# I have a string that I get in a jQuery callback and that looks like

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I get in a jQuery callback and that looks like this 792-1816vh1,792-1816vh2 and I want to convert it to '792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2'.
How can I do that?
Any help appreciated, thanks.

So this is my problem:

I need to send some userid to a function, and that function is sending a push notification. And it works if the variable with the userid:s looks like "users" below, and is hardcoded in the js file. I also have two other variables with text.

```
var usersfromarray = strArray[2];//from a callback, not working
console.log(usersfromarray)//this writes 792-1816vh1,792-1816vh2
var users='792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2'//this is hardcoded in the js file.
var pushtext="Some text..."
var tid="now"

var str='792-1816vh1,792-1816vh2';
var res='';

str.split(',').forEach(function(elem) {
res += "'" + elem + "',";
});

// remove last ","
res = res.substring(0, res.length-1);

console.log(res);//this writes '792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2'
```

I send it to the function like this:

```
skickaPushnotiser([[pushtext,tid],users]);
```

If I use "users" then it is working, it sends the push.

If I use "res" then it is not working, even if it writes the same in the console as the "users".

Both "users" and "res" is writing: '792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2' in the console.

So why is "users" working and not "res"? I don´t know what Im missing?
I would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Edit: I need "res" to be ["792-1816vh1", "792-1816vh2"], with the brackets and with " instead of ' 
Thanks.

Comment: SO you want to turn it into an array? Just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the comma

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be with the ' character and not " as I guess it becomes with split, or? From w3school it just becomes 792-1816vh1,792-1816vh2 with a split and I need it to be with the ' character. '792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it to an array using `split(',')` and the append it back using a loop:

```js
var str='792-1816vh1,792-1816vh2';
var res='[';

str.split(',').forEach(function(elem) {
   res += '"' + elem + '", ';
});

// remove last ","
res = res.substring(0, res.length-2) + ']';

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks Koby, great, thanks. I will test and see if it work for my specific needs.

Comment: How can I change it so that "res" looks like this instead  ["792-1816vh1", "792-1816vh2"]. Thanks a lot Koby.

Comment: Thanks Koby, I now get this in the console ["792-1816vh1","792-1816vh2"] and it does´t work, but if I use the other one(hard coded) then I get this in the console and the userid:s are red and the first one is black ["792-1816vh1", "792-1816vh2"] (2), so the difference is a space after the comma and that the hardcoded one is red and it writes (2) after it as well. I have tried to get the space but with no luck.

Comment: Great will test. What is the difference between them? Why is one black and why i s one red?

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson I have no idea... I can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, now I get ['792-1816vh1', '792-1816vh2',] so it is not removing the last comma, and also, can you change the ' to " :-)

Comment: I see in your example above that you get a space after the comma, but I don´t? I get ["792-1816vh1", "792-1816vh2"]

Comment: thats with a space... what you just wrote

Comment: When I use your code it does´t show a space in my console, but it does in your code above. Strange. If I use this, then it works, but with yours it does´t, and I don´t understand why. var test=['792-1816vh1','792-1816vh2'] console.log(test); And with this I get this in the console. ["792-1816vh1", "792-1816vh2"] (2)

Comment: Now I got it working. It treated it as a array with integer values and not string values. Thanks a lot for your help Koby!