# JavaScript split string by specific character string

Tags: javascript

I have a text box with a bunch of comments, all separated by a specific character string as a means of splitting them to display each comment individually.

The string in question is *|* but I can change this to accommodate whatever will work. My only requirement is that it is not likely to be a string of characters someone will type in an everyday sentence.

I believe I need to use the split method and possibly some regex but all the other questions I've seen only seem to mention splitting by one character or a number of different characters, not a specific set of characters in a row.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` should work for that purpose:

```
var comments = "this is a comment|and here is another comment|and yet another one";
var parsedComments = comments.split('|');
```

This will give you all comments in an array which you can then loop over or do whatever you have to do.

Keep in mind you could also change `|` to something like `<--NEWCOMMENT-->` and it will still work fine inside the `split('<--NEWCOMMENT-->')` method.

Remember that `split()` *removes* the character it's splitting on, so your resulting array won't contain any instances of `<--NEWCOMMENT-->`

Comment: Thanks, I'll get my coat. I didn't realise I could do it like that. For some reason I thought it could only be a single character.

Comment: Nice, mark the question as answered if it answered it :)