# How to split string from particular word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[
    { 
    docPath: "c:\Project\Indofebweb\Attachment\images\indofab.png",
    }
]
```

I want to split the string from **\Attachment** and get the rest of the string e.g
**\Attachment\images\indofab.png** . How can I do this?

Comment: try using regular expressions

Comment: Here's two links to get you started: [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) & [`string.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: if `c:\Project\Indofebweb\\` is a constant path try `path = test.replace('c:\Project\Indofebweb','');`

Comment: Here's another one: [`string.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular string you can use :

```
var arr=test.split("Indofebweb");
var restString=arr[1];  //-----contains string \Attachment\images\indofab.png
```

You can make your own logic using split() function.

***UPDATED CODE----TRY THIS----BELOW HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> a string display :</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "c:\\Project\\Indofebweb\\Attachment\\images\\indofab.png";; 
    var arr=str.split("Indofebweb");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[1];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: output:  Attachmentimagesindofab.png but expected output is Attachment\images\indofab.png

Comment: make your sting as "c:\\Project\\Indofebweb\\Attachment\\images\\indofab.png";

Comment: because '\' is a escape character

Comment: how i put \ in the output string?

Comment: how you are getting this path, share that then i can help

Comment: I m getting: Attachmentimagesindofab.png

Comment: share your code that extract path, and let me check

Comment: its is the question itself

Comment: I have updated my code try that, as i am getting correct output

Comment: my string is the javascript object [{ docPath : "c:\Project\Indofebweb\Attachment\images\indofab.png"}] in this stringi want a split.

Answer (score 0):

use str.match()

```
    path.match(/\\Attachment.*/);
```

this will return everything after and including "\Attachment". Keep in mind that backslashes need to be escaped.

Comment: but my expected output is this: \Attachment\images\indofab.png .

Comment: and this is what my solution will show. but you need to escape the path before you put it into your js.

Comment: my string is the javascript object [{ docPath : "c:\Project\Indofebweb\Attachment\images\indofab.png"}] in this stringi want a split.

Comment: Where does this object come from? Can you change it?

Comment: from API response.

Comment: you need to change the api response. the \ get lost as soon as they are in your js. look: https://jsfiddle.net/58q3nt09/

Comment: there is no other way to achieve this?