# splitting a string with a decimal number and some characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have strings like:
       '1234picas'
        '1234 px'
        '145.4us'

I want to split them in two parts: the numeric part and the non numeric one. For example:   '1234.4us' need to be splitted in '1234.4' and 'us'. I am tempted to insert a separator between the last digit and the non numeric and use split but is there a better way to do this in JavaScript

Thanks

Note: this is not the slitting of a string at special char. it could be converted to that but this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Use a Regular Expression

Comment: I was reading RegExp for Scala and I got more confused... I'll look into this again

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character

Comment: And https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-ab&ei=fWfWWrLZL-2E_QbxoLVI&q=how+to+split+a+string+with+special+characters+site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript&oq=how+to+split+a+string+with+special+characters+site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4679.5783.0.5845.11.9.0.0.0.0.131.688.4j4.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.L2FlEis3IH0 for nearly 1 million other results

Comment: This is not the splitting of a string at special character. This could be a path to follow but I am trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`String.prototype.match()`](http://String.prototype.match()):

```js
const a = '1234picas';
const b = '1234 px';
const c = '145.4us';

function split(input) {
  const splitArray = input.match(/([\d\.]+)(.*)/); // match only digits and decimal points in the first group and match the rest of the string in second group
  
  return {
    numeric: splitArray[1],
    nonnumeric: splitArray[2],
  };
}

console.log(split(a));
console.log(split(b));
console.log(split(c));
```

[Regex explanation | Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ifjIcd/1)

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do it using [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) , you can add it to the `Sting.prototype` if you want :

```js
const str1 = '1234picas',
  str2 = '1234 px',
  str3 = '145.4us';

String.prototype.split = function () {
  const num = parseFloat(this);
  const alph = this.slice(num.toString().length, this.length)

  return {
    num,
    alph
  }
}


console.log(str1.split());
console.log(str2.split());
console.log(str3.split());
```

Comment: All those variables can be `const` instead of `let` :)

Comment: @RahulDesai yes you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split` with a regex using a lookahead:

```
str.split(/(?=[^\d.-])/g))
   .map(y => [
         y[0],
         y.slice(1).join('').trim()
   ])
```

```js
x = ["1234picas", "1234 px", "145.4us"];

console.log(x.map(y => 
    y.split(/(?=[^\d.-])/g))
     .map(y => [
         y[0],
         y.slice(1).join('').trim()
     ])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
var a = "4343.453fsdakfjdsa";
a.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[\d\.?]+/ig);
```

[MDN for String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

It basically says match the alphabetical letters OR match numbers with an optional period. The ig is insensitive (which is not really needed) and global as in don't return on the first match, keep going until all of the string has been parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Regex!
Here is how it works: https://regex101.com/r/XbI7Mq/1

```js
const test = ['1234picas', '1234 px', '145.4us', 'no'];
const regex = /^(\d+\.?\d+)\s?(.*)/;
test.forEach(i => {
  const result = regex.exec(i);
  if (result) {
    console.log(result[1], result[2])
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in javascript to split:

```
var myString = '145.4us';
var splits = myString.split(/(\d+\.?\d+)/);
console.log(splits);
```