# how to get the last digit from format like ip address javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Does anyone know how can I get the last digits `192.168.1.180`
**Example :** 192.168.1.180 from this ip address i want to extract 180.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if that ip address is a string you could always use the split function.

```js
let str = "192.168.1.180";
let x = str.split(".")[3]; 
// where str is the ip and x is the last part you want to extract

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
let ip = '192.168.1.180';
let last = ip.split('.')[3];
console.log(last); // '180'
```