# How to break a string in Java script and store them as variables

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have the following text: `"configuration/entities/details/attributes/FirstName".`
I want to break it in such a way that, **attributes** and **FirstName** should come out separately, preferably as two variables.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: Really? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split . I seriously cannot believe if you'd searched online for a few moments you would not have found the solution to this straight away. Did you even look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Answer (score 2):

If the structure is always the same, with attribute and name at the end, you can do:

```js
let text = "configuration/entities/details/attributes/FirstName"
let arr = text.split("/"); //["configuration",  "entities","details",  "attributes",  "FirstName"]
let reverse_arr = arr.reverse();
let [name,attr] = reverse_arr;

console.log(name, attr)
```

The `split` separates by "/", the `reverse()` well reverses it, then with destructuring, you say that "take the first two and put it in two variables"

It wont matter if there are more or less elements elements if those two are at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can do such as this:

```
let targetString="configuration/entities/details/attributes/FirstName";
let splitArray=targetString.split('/');
let attributes=splitArray[splitArray.length-1]
```