# How to slice/extract 8 characters after second comma in a string ? Note: Dynamic string length, and comma position is not static

Tags: javascript

I would like to split/extract the 8 characters which are always between the second and third comma in a string. Earlier, I split the 8 characters from 24 to 31 position in a string, but the position can vary based on the position of the commas.

#### Example of string:

`var mystr = “1xxxxxxxx,2xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,9xxxxxxx,0xxxxxxx,XX,Rxxxxxxx,”;`.

var neededcode = Code.slice(23,31);

Output should be `“9xxxxxxx”`.

Comment: Okay, so what did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: @CertainPerformance is regex necessary here? You can just use the built-in split function to find it.

Comment: @JackMoody I agree. An alternative is to also look up occurrences of commas and calculate the index range to extract.

Comment: @JackMoody Oh, you're right, I missed the fact that the desired match will always be between two commas. https://jsfiddle.net/o5hfy4b6/

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript `split()` function seems to be what you are after. This function allows you to create an array. In your example, this would return `["1xxxxxxxx","2xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","9xxxxxxx","0xxxxxxx","XX","Rxxxxxxx"]`. Then, to find the value after the second comma and before the third comma, you would just take the third element of the array using `mystr.split(",")[2]`.

#### Code

```js
var mystr = "1xxxxxxxx,2xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,9xxxxxxx,0xxxxxxx,XX,Rxxxxxxx,";
    
var mysplit = mystr.split(",")[2];
console.log(mysplit);
```

#### Output

> 9xxxxxxx