# Split string without any built-in functions

Tags: javascript, loops

I need a function that works like `split`

`var string = "a|b|c"
console.log(string.split('|'))`

to get a string and split it **using loop**

```
function splitstr(str, charToSplit){

      }
```

I want the output of `('a|b|c', '|')` to be `["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character)

Comment: @DevJem this question is not related to that proposed dupe question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below.

This code had 8 steps to it.

1. Loops through the string
2. Checks if the current item is equal to `charToSplit`
3. If it is, it loops through the values in between `startIndex` and your current index (excluding your current index, which is the character you want to split on)
4. It first sets the value of `output[currentIndex]` to an empty string (since using `+=` on something that doesn't exist doesn't work correctly
5. Then it adds the current letter you are on to `output`
6. `startIndex` is set to your current index + 1 (which is the character after the character that you want to split on)
7. `currentIndex` is increased by 1 since you're now on the next set of values
8. Finally, the code returns `output`

**Note:** The final extra loop after the first loop is there to add the last value to your `output` array.

```js
function splitstr(str, charToSplit) {
  var output = [];
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var startIndex = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == charToSplit) {
      output[currentIndex] = "";
      for (var x = startIndex; x < i; x++) {
        output[currentIndex] += str[x];
      }
      startIndex = i + 1;
      currentIndex++;
    }
  }
  output[currentIndex] = "";
  for (var i = startIndex; i < str.length; i++) {
    output[currentIndex] += str[i];
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(splitstr("abc|abcd|ac", "|"));
```

Comment: Thanks but are there any other way to do this by not using built-in functions `push` and `subtring` ??

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining every step, appreciate that.

Comment: @NewUser yw. Give me a few mins to work on a solution without built-in functions

Comment: @NewUser I updated my snippet to work without built in functions. Let me update my explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot,  how about the output of `('abc|abcd|ac', '|')` shoudn't it be `["abc","abcd","ac"]` ??? cause it returns `["c", "d", "c"]` (it returns the last char of the string)

Comment: `output[currentIndex] = "";` should be before the second loop

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly simpler solution that works correctly:

```js
function splitStr(str, separator) {
  const parts = [];
  let nextPart = '';
  for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === separator || i === str.length) {
      parts[parts.length] = nextPart;
      nextPart = '';
    } else {
      nextPart += str[i]
    }
  }
  return parts;
}

console.log(splitStr("abc|abcd|ac", "|"));
```