# How can I replace string between digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

`const value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"`

I want to remove 'XXXX' and add ',' instead of 'XXXX'.
How can I do that?

My expected value is : `"12345,98765"`.
And then I want an array with elements of value. My array should be like this:

`var array = [];
array[0] = "12345",
array[1] = "98765"`

How can I do that?

I try this code: `value.replace("XXXX", ",")` but it shows XXXX again.

Comment: `.replace()` doesn't modify the original string. It works on a copy and returns the changed version

Comment: `value.match(/\d+/g)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try a regex replacement, followed by a string split:

```js
var value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"
value = value.replace(/XXXX/mg, ",").replace(/,$/, "");
parts = value.split(",");
console.log(parts);
```

Note that the second regex replacement conditionally removes a final trailing comma, should the string happen to end in `XXXX` (which in your example, it does).  Should no trailing comma be present, the second replacement would just no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"

const result = value
  .replace(/[^\d]+/g, ',') // replace any consequent non-digit symbols with single comma
  .replace(/,$/, '') // trim off the last comma if any
  
console.info("String: " + result)

// or if you are looking to obtain the array directly, you can do:

const arr = value
  .split(/[^\d]+/) // split on consequent non-digit symbols
  .filter(Boolean) // filter out empty items
  
console.info("Array: ", arr)
```

Notice that the above snippets will work no matter if you have `X` as placeholder or any other letter and number of them (4 or more or less) also doesn't matter.

Comment: I guess what they want is just `value.match(/\d+/g)`

Answer (score 1):

For sneak peeking proposals, The full code is here:

```js
var value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  if(value[i] === 'X') {
    value = value.replace('XXXX', ',')
  }
}
value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1)
var parts = value.split(',')
console.info(parts)
```

If you want to know more about each part, you can read below:

> I want to remove 'XXXX' and add ',' instead of 'XXXX'. How can I do that?

First of all, you need to use something called *replace()*, but how you want to remove all the occurrences of *'XXXX'*, you can do a for loop searching for any 'X' you could find.

*reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace*

```
var value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) { //looking through the whole string
    if(value[i] === 'X') { //For any X found
        value = value.replace('XXXX', ',') //you should replace them for a comma
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, the last 'XXXX' also became a comma, so to remove it just use *substring()*.

*reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring*

```
value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1)
```

So, now you have a string just like you wanted. **"12345,98765"**

For splitting and getting the values that are before and after the comma, you can use *split()* and save the result in a new variable, which is an array.

*reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split*

```
var parts = value.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `replace` it only changes one time
you have to use a regex instead

`value.replace(/XXX/g, ",")`

Later you can use `split` to convert that string into an array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the return of `replace()`?

`array = value.replace("XXXX",",");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the return value of replace

```
value = value.replace("XXXX",",");
```

Also since you declared it as a `const` you won't be able to reassign so use a `let` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` with regex for the matching tokens (XXXX):

```js
const value = "12345XXXX98765XXX";
var res = value.replace(/[X]+/g, ',').replace(/,$/, '').split(',');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yeah @TimBiegeleisen your answer is identical to mine

Answer (score 0):

.replace() returns a new string (it does not modify the existing string). You need to do the following:

value = value.replace("XXXX", ",")

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX";

value = value.split("XXXX");

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want an array, the obvious way would be to use split instead of replace

```js
const value = "12345XXXX98765XXXX"
console.log(value.split('XXXX', 2))
```